# CouchDB not starting "unexpected operator"

Tags: couchdb, ubuntu-14.04

I am running couchdb on an Ubuntu 14.04 server and today I noticed it had stopped running (on the test server, not the production one, thankfully). When I try to start it again, it comes back with the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/couchdb: 214: test: -gt: unexpected operator
```

I have tried rebooting the server to be sure there is no other instance of couch running, but the problem is still occurring.

Comment: Are you trying to start this manually or through your init system?  Could you post the command you are attempting to start Couch with?

Comment: I'm trying to start it manually, since it is failing to start when I reboot the server. I'm just using "service couchdb start"

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was being an idiot. There are two commands that start it and I was using the wrong one.